# NestJs cannot find any module when ran in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile, nestjs

I have this Dockerfile that is supposed to run my nest.js project:

```
# syntax:docker/dockerfile:1

#base
FROM node:16.14.2-alpine AS base

ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm i -g npm@8.19.3 @nestjs/cli

COPY ["./package.json", "./"]

#dev
FROM base AS dev

RUN npm i
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]

#prod
FROM base AS prod

COPY . .

RUN npm i --frozen-lockfile --production

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

and when I run it with this docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:

  backend:                                      #THE BACKEND SIDE OF OUR APP ITSELF :
    build:
      context: ./back 
      #dockerfile: ./back/Dockerfile
      target: dev #for multi stage
    env_file:
      - ./env/back.env
    ports:
      - 2000:2000
    volumes:
      - ./back:/app
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - database
    restart: unless-stopped

  database:                                      #THE POSTGRESQL DATABASE
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  #  env_file:
  #    - ./env/postgres.env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: transcendeur
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: bigData
      POSTGRES_DB: transcendb
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  databaseadmin:                                 #THE DATABASE 'ADMIN GRAPHICAL INTERFACE'
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 5050:80
    env_file:
      - ./env/pgadmin.env
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: nidma@nidma.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: dimnagp4
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./docker/pgadmin_servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json
    depends_on:
      - database
    logging:
      driver: none

  # frontend:                                       #THE FRONTEND SIDE OF OUR APP ITSELF :
  #   build:
  #     dockerfile: front/Dockerfile
  #   env_file:
  #     - ./env/front.env
  #   ports:
  #     - 8080:8080
  #   restart: unless-stopped
  #   networks:
  #     - backend
  #   volumes:
  #     - ./front:/app
  #   depends_on:
  #     - backend
    

volumes:
  postgres:
  back:

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

Everything builds fine until `npm run start:dev`, at compilation my files in `src` folder can't resolve any modules (for example `@nestjs/common` is not found)

Here's my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "back",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "DB_ENVFILE=db nest start",
    "start:dev": "DB_ENVFILE=db nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "DB_ENVFILE=db nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "DB_ENVFILE=db node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "DB_ENVFILE=db jest",
    "test:watch": "DB_ENVFILE=db jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "DB_ENVFILE=db jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "DB_ENVFILE=db node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "DB_ENVFILE=db jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^2.2.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "*",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^6.1.3",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.1",
    "pg": "^8.8.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.5.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "28.1.8",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "28.1.3",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "28.0.8",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

I'm stuck on this since this morning and I can't find any solution on other posts, my Dockerfile looks fine I don't see where could be the problem

EDIT: I forgot to say that it works perfectly fine without docker when running the same commands

The error message I get is the same as if I did `npm run start::dev` without the node_modules folder

Comment: Providing an explicit error would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do copy first the `package.json` and later your whole code into the working directory (`/app`) of your image in your `Dockerfile` and you run `npm i` in that directory while building.

But in your `docker-compose.yml` you bind-mount the `./back/` directory over the container's `/app/` which makes the previous `npm install` irrelevant since now the contents of `./back/` are in that directory and not the ones baked into the image.

So as long as there is no `node_modules` directory on your host `./back/` the modules can not be found.

Comment: So if I just change the path of my volume it should work without having node_modules ?

Comment: No, if you bind-mount the `./back` directory into the container to use the source code files directly from the host while developing (which is what I assume you want to do) you also need the dependencies installed on the host. But you could use the `npm` inside the container to do this once, e.g. with `docker-compose run --rm backend npm i`.